# How to send Push Notifications using php in flutter App?

Tags: php, flutter, dart

Here I have two Applications. One acts like Admin and the other is a customer.

When I'm uploading an image in the admin App that image was displayed in the customer app. Here am using PHP as a backend to post images in the admin app and to get images in the customer app. My question is - I want to send a notification to the customer when the admin uploads the image.

> Note: If possible, I need to do this task without using Firebase.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I try to explain the process in steps:

Assuming your Flutter app is properly integrated with [Firebase FCM](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging)

1. Admin post an image
2. Server sends a push notification, you may refer to fcm http protocol [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) or the json structure of your fcm body below

```
{
 "to" : "<TOKEN>", //if you want the fcm to be sent to specific user
 "notification" : {
     "title": "Notification Title",
     "body" : "Notification Body"
 },
 "data":{
    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK",
    "key": "<ANY STRING YOU WOULD LIKE TO DIFFERENTIATE THE NOTIFICATION>" //eg: "image_update"
 }
}
```

3. In Flutter code, configure `onMessage` to tell the app what is needed to be performed when the push notification with key "image_update" is received

```
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      if(message.data['key'] == "image_update"){
         //call GET image API and display on app
      }
      //note: you can differentiate notification type with "key" so that you can perform different functions for each notification type
      return;
    });
```

Comment: Is this Free in firebase?

Comment: according to https://firebase.google.com/pricing , Cloud Messaging (FCM) is free

Comment: yeah! thanks buddy..